# How to get "key" prop from React element (on change)?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to get option's value and key when select `onChange`.

I know I can get option's *value* simplicity used `event.target.value` in `onChangeOption` function, but how can I get `key`?

```
<select onChange={this.onChangeOption} value={country}>
    {countryOptions.map((item, key) =>
        <option key={key} value={item.value}>
            {item.name}
        </option>
    )}
</select>
```

Answer (score 63, accepted):

Passing key as a prop works obviously, but much quicker way could be to include the key as a custom attribute in your html.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.onSelect = this.onSelect.bind(this);
  }
  onSelect(event) {
    const selectedIndex = event.target.options.selectedIndex;
        console.log(event.target.options[selectedIndex].getAttribute('data-key'));
  }

  render() {
    return ( 
      <div>
      <select onChange = {this.onSelect}>
       <option key="1" data-key="1">One</option> 
       <option key="2" data-key="2">Two</option>             </select> 
     </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render( < App / > , document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: What is selectedIndex here? `event.target.options.selectedIndex`;

Comment: There is actually a nicer way of accessing these `data-*` attributes, and it is detailed [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes). In short, you can use `element.dataset.<attribute_name>` to get the value of the attribute. In this case, doing `event.target.options[selectedIndex].datasets.key` also works

Answer (score 86):

You will need to pass value in key as a different prop.

From docs:

> Keys serve as a hint to React but they don’t get passed to your components. If you need the same value in your component, pass it explicitly as a prop with a different name:

Read: https://reactjs.org/docs/lists-and-keys.html

Comment: This is a bad answer. it doesn't propose a solution or take into consideration he's dealing with a native `select` field so this may be used in a form of some sort which may break if replaced with a custom component

Comment: Thanks for reply, I have read docs,  but still have a question.  Does that mean I "have to" pass value in key as a different prop, so that I can get the key?

Comment: Yes, it means that.

Answer (score 6):

A simple way of doing this is:

```
const functionCall = (event) => {
    console.log(event.target.getAttribute('a-key'));
}

<button a-key={1} onClick={functionCall}>Press Me</button>
```

I put onClick but you can use any event.

Answer (score 3):

Imagine a component like this:

```
<Component data={[{id:'a23fjeZ', name="foo"}, ...]}`
```

Which renders a list of inputs, and gets in a `data` prop which is a collection (*Array* of *Objects*):

```
function Component ( props ){
    // cached handler per unique key. A self-invoked function with a "cache" object
    const onChange = (cache => param => {
        if( !cache[param] )
            cache[param] = e => 
                console.log(param, e.target.name, e.target.value)

        return cache[param];
    }
    )({});

    return props.data.map(item =>
        <input key={item.id} name={item.name} onChange={onChange(item.id)} />
    }

}
```

As you can see, the `key` isn't being accessed, but is passed into a [currying function](https://medium.com/javascript-scene/curry-and-function-composition-2c208d774983) which is handling the caching internally, to prevent "endless" creation of functions on re-renders.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass anything through `value`. I think this solves your problem.

```
<select onChange={this.handleChange}>
        {this.state.countryOptions.map((item, key) =>
          <option key={key} 
            value={JSON.stringify({key, value:item.value})}>
            //passing index along with value
            {item.value}
          </option>
        )}
</select>

handleChange(e) {
    let obj = JSON.parse(e.target.value) 
   // gives object{ key:country index, value: country value}
  }
```

Comment: @vsync
I think that is the requirement here.
Could you please explain your comment further?

Comment: the `value` prop must be the value and not some abomination of a stringified object. that is irrelevant to the server (in all likelihood). This has been the way for some 20 years. Everybody else got it right, but implemented their solutions in a non-optimal way.

Answer (score 2):

I'm a beginner and have battle with this for days now!
Now, I will be happy to share you my final answer!

This is really easy -All you got to do is to declare an anonymous function! for an onClick on the item you wanna detect its key!

e.g

```
data.map((item) => (<div
className = "newItem" key = {item.id} onClick = {() = displayKey(item.id)}
>{item.value}</div>))
```

then your function can be thus;
will display any "val" passed in

```
const displayKey = (val) => {
    console.log(val)
}
```

I hope I was able to help!
battling with a problem can be a pain in the ass!
Kind Regards .

Answer (score 1):

So you do need to pass the key into the `<option>` as a prop, but since the `<select>` is a native field and handles changes internally it gets a little hard to get that key value back out.
Lets start one issue at a time, passing the prop into the option could be as simple as wrapping the option component like so and using the `index` prop as the new key prop.

```
const CustomOption = ({ value, children, index }) => (
    <option key={index} value={value}>{value}</option>
);
```

Also note that we're creating a custom component wrapper above to swallow the `index` prop from being applied to `<option />` itself as react doesnt like unknown props on dom elements.

Now if we could handle the selected event inside the option we would be done, but we can't do that. so we need to make a custom select as well:

```
class CustomSelect extends React.Component {

    static propTypes = {
        value: PropTypes.object,
        onChange: PropTypes.func,
    }

    handleChanged = (e) => {
        const newValue = e.target.value;
        let newKey;

        // iterate through our children searching for the <CustomOption /> that was just selected
        React.children.forEach(this.children, (c) => {
            if (c.props && c.props.index && c.props.value === newValue) {
                newKey = c.props.key;
            }
        });

        this.props.onChange(e, newKey);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <select value={this.props.value} onChange={this.handleChanged}>
                {this.props.children}
            </select>
        );
    }
}
```

it has two props `value`, and `onChange`. Notice that we intercept the change event in order to find the index (the key) and we pass it along to the parent as the second parameter. This is not very nice but I can't think of another easy way to do this while still using the native `<select>` element.

Note you need to replace your usages of `<select>` and `<optoin>` to use these new classes, and assign the `index` prop along with the `key` prop on the option.

Comment: This is great, I haven't thought of this way before.

Answer (score 0):

This also works neatly for me:

```
const element: JSX.Element = <div key="my-key" />

const key = element.key?.valueOf()

console.log(key) // prints "my-key"
```